# Unable to add new object to List past index 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm noticing that I am unable to add to a list of objects past index 0. Any other index returns a null reference.

```
public class MultiValidation
{
    public List<SingleValidation> validations { get; set; }

    public MultiValidation(List<string> numArray)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i<numArray.Count; i++)
        {
            SingleValidation individual = new SingleValidation(Validate.idArray[i], Validate.actionArray[i], Validate.expiryArray[i]);
            validations = new List<SingleValidation>();
            validations.Add(individual);
            Console.WriteLine(validations[i].action);
        }
    }
```

Here is the constructor used for `SingleValidation`

```
public SingleValidation(string ide, string ac, string exDate)
{
    this.action = ac;
    this.expiry = exDate;
    this.id = ide;
}
```

I have tested that `idArray[i]`,`actionArray[i]`,`expiryArray[i]` are all strings.

Comment: You are creating a new list instance inside the loop

Comment: @Plutonix wow I am stupid.... thank you so much!!!!

Comment: You may want to delete this question now as it's not really helpful for future visitors.

Comment: explain what is validate is here Validate.idArray[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validations = new List<SingleValidation>();
```

This should be outside the for loop.

```
{
validations = new List<SingleValidation>();
for(int i = 0; i<numArray.Count; i++)
    {
        SingleValidation individual = new SingleValidation(Validate.idArray[i], 
        Validate.actionArray[i], Validate.expiryArray[i]);
        validations.Add(individual);
        Console.WriteLine(validations[i].action);
    }
}
```